# How to create an object through loop using vue multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue multiselect for a project with laravel.
The selected values are saved in the database in this way.

```
['value_on','value_two','value_three', and so on...]
```

In the part where the user can do the updates I need to display the values coming from the database. 
This is the object I need to create

```
   sizeValue: [
               {size: 'val_one},
              {size: 'val_two},
               {size: 'val_three}
              ...and so on

            ]
```

Right now I just have an empty array where I should loop the data from the database.

```
 //This is the empty array
 sizeValue: [];

//This is the array coming from the server it will return['val_one','val_two','val_three',...and so on]
product.sizes
```

Since I don't have much experience with javascript I would like to ask how I can get this result

```
     sizeValue: [
               {size: 'val_one},
              {size: 'val_two},
               {size: 'val_three}
              ...and so on

            ]
```

looping the values (product.sizes) coming from the DB in the empty sizeValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply create the `sizeValue` as a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) and use the javascript `map` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

This could look like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    sizeValue() {
      return this.product.sizes.map(productSize => {
        return {
          size: productSize
        };
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)